# Installer says no Operative System Found

Tags: ubiquity, system-installation

I try to install Bbuntu with Usb and bootloader when I come to the step partition. There don't pop up any partition in that menu. Only that error pops up. The computer I try to install ubuntu on is a asus Eee PC P1001. And this mini pc has been caused by American Megatrends boot up.

There is no OS on it.

Comment: Your question is unclear, if there is one at all, also could you provide a more detailed description of what you are experiencing? What error is displayed, what version of Ubuntu are you trying to install and which steps did you take to mount the ISO to the drive, what DOES display in the partition setup?

Comment: LOOOK i send pictures up here if you dont see that and im follow that usb bootloader guide on ubuntu.com

Answer (score 2):

The fact that there is no OS on it is exactly what that error is saying. There is not boot-able file system on the disk. The disk is clean, unallocated space. You have to create a partition on it for you to see one. The installer can do this automatically if you chose for it to install without going to "Something else". You should be bale to re-size the partition size if you do not want it to take up the whole disk.

Comment: im a newbie on this were should i press to get that automatically install thing. can you send a instruction or picture please. cause im not good on this

Comment: It should be an option on the menu. After the "Preparing to Install Ubuntu." Window, there is an "installation type" window. The first option, since there is no OS, should be something like "Erase and Install Ubuntu" Use that option.

Comment: [IMG]http://i.imgur.com/EcYRDX5.png[/IMG] Should i click here

Comment: @CatWbut do you know im installing from a USB

Comment: I know you are installing from a USB yes. Also, yes you should click there. YOU should click there and then click "Install Ubuntu"> A window will show showing "Preparing to Install Ubuntu" and then the one I was talking about.

Comment: Now im are on that window you talking about http://i.imgur.com/FdRBTdc.png what should a do now

Comment: if i press Continue it takes me to that empty partition menu and i get that error

Comment: this is that evil menu i get if i press Continue http://i.imgur.com/Gb9xD02.png

Comment: and this is the error http://i.imgur.com/yn7wc5g.png

Comment: When you click okay does the installer close? If it does not and it stays open, you can try to create a new partition table by pressing that option, and then making up your partition to set up Ubuntu afterwards.

Comment: Yes its stays open but i can not press that option